# copy file in android template changed the file content

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-3.0

I modify the Android Studio's project-template, in the recipe.xml file, I add one line:

```
<copy from="root/Key" to="${escapeXmlAttribute(topOut)}/Key" />
```

and when I create new Android project, the Key indeed was created, but actually the file was modified, and I can't use it which gave errors:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:795)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

Comment: Why did you add that line? I didn't get it correctly.

Comment: so that I needn't to add the Key manually every time, and all my workmates do